# Segmentation fault during fscanf()?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

This is my beginner program experimentation with what I have learned on dynamic memory allocation, pointers, and files. Every time I compile I keep having a segmentation fault. I haven't been able to fix this error that occurs during `fscanf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// create int aboveavg();

double average(int *ptr, int size){
        int count = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        while(count <= size){
                sum += *ptr;
                ptr++;
                count++;
        }
        sum /= size;
        return sum;
}
int main(){
        int n = 10;
        int *ptr = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int)); //allocate dynamic memory
        printf("Allocated %d integers\n", n);
        FILE *input = fopen("a.txt" , "r");      //open file
        if(input = NULL){                        //error check
                printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
                exit(0);
        }
        int count = 0, i=0;
        printf("check point\n");
        while(fscanf(input, "%d", &ptr[i]) == 1){  //**Segmentation Fault**
                if(count == n){
                        n *=2;
                        ptr = (int*)realloc(ptr,n* sizeof(int));
                        printf("Reallocated to %d integers\n", n);
                }
                i++;
                count++;
        }
        fclose(input);
        double avg = average(ptr, n);
        printf("average of %f\n", avg);
        free(ptr);
        printf("Dynamic array freed\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Searching for an answer (google or stack overflow), hasn't really helped me. Can anyone can hint/point to what I did wrong.

Comment: `if(input = NULL){` --> `if(input == NULL){ `, `while(count <= size){` --> `while(count < size){`

Comment: change `if(input = NULL){` to `if(input == NULL){` for a start

Comment: also, ` exit(0);` usually indicates that the program ran successfully.  A non-zero exit code would be better in this case.

Comment: Get your hand on your debugger

Comment: Also `"Error! memory not allocated."` --> `"Error! Can't open file."`

Comment: `double avg = average(ptr, n);` --> `double avg = average(ptr, count);`

Comment: `average(int *ptr, int size)` is adding `size + 1` numbers together.  I'd expect `size` numbers.

Comment: I have added the changes and tried debugging using gdb. I am still struggling with the segmentation fault. Am I perhaps over riding my pointers or not storing them properly? I tried using temp values and fgets(), but no luck. @BLUEPIXY

Comment: `if(count == n){` Too late. Because This already use `ptr[n]` (element `ptr[n]` is out of bounds.) try [this](http://ideone.com/VoBXGY)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.